# Asynchronous Pool of Connections in Tornado with multiple processes

Tags: asynchronous, elasticsearch, tornado, connection-pooling, pool

I'm using both **Tornado 4.2.1** and **tornadoes 2.4.1** libraries to query my Elasticsearch database and I'm looking for a way to initialize a *Pool of connections* to shared between several RequestHandler instances in a multiple processes service.

Is it possible to do that? Are there specific libraries for Tornado to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `tornado-es` is just a HTTP client, it uses [`AsyncHTTPClient`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/httpclient.py#L106) in the [`ESConnection`](https://github.com/globocom/tornado-es/blob/master/tornadoes/__init__.py#L18). The **new TCP connection is made every request**, unless `Connection: keep-alive` header is specified.

```
conn = ESConnection()
conn.httprequest_kwargs['headers'] = {'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

I've not tested, but it should work. I used similar setup in ruby (with [patron](https://github.com/toland/patron) http client), and it works well

**Next thing**

`AsyncHTTPClient` has limit of maximum number of simultaneous requests (`fetch`) per ioloop. Every request that hit the limit is just queued internally.

You may want to increase the global limit:

```
AsyncHTTPClient.configure(None, max_clients=50)
```

or separate the client with its own limit (`force_instance`):

```
from tornadoes import ESConnection
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

class CustomESConnection(ESConnection):

    def __init__(self, , host='localhost', port='9200', io_loop=None, protocol='http', max_clients=20):
        super(CustomESConnection, self).__init__(host, port, io_loop, protocol)
        self.client = AsyncHTTPClient(force_instance=True, max_clients=max_clients)
```

**And finally**

To reuse the same ESConnection you can create it in the Application, since the application is available with every request (RequestHandler)

```
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler
from tornadoes import ESConnection

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        yield self.application.es.search('something')


class MyApp(Application):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.es = ESconnection()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = MyApp([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

**Multiprocess**

Actually there is no easy way. The common approach is a pooler, which is used mostly when persistent connection is needed, like databases ([pgbouncer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) for postgres) or as a optimization on high-load service.

And you will have to write a pooler, a gateway application to es

```
subprocess1 
           \  (http, zmq, ...)
            \            
              > pooler (some queue and tornadoes api) - http -> elastisearch
            /
           /
subprocess2
```

The subprocesses could communicate with pooler via HTTP, [ØMQ](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/pyzmq.html) (there are many examples even pooler) or some implementation of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (sockects, ...).

Comment: Hi @kwarunek and thank you very much for your answer. I totally understand what you said and it works perfect. The only thing I don't understand is if is it possible use it with multiple sub-processes.

Inside my main I've implemented a mechanism where I get from command line how many sub-processes to start, in this way:

`http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(MyApp)`

`http_server.bind(8888)`

`http_server.start(tornado.options.options.processes)`

`tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()`

Is it possible use your example within multiple sub-processes?

Comment: I tried to start my Tornado with 2 sub-processes and I got this error:
`RuntimeError: Cannot run in multiple processes: IOLoop instance has already been initialized. You cannot call IOLoop.instance() before calling start_processes()`.

Comment: I've added note about multiprocess.

Comment: And the runtime error is caused probably because creating AsyncHTTPClient before forking as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641015/run-multiple-tornado-processess

Comment: Thanks a lot @kwarunek, that's perfect!